# Using nvcc with CUDA 6 and VS 2012 Express

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2012, cuda, nvcc

I'm trying to get started with CUDA and a 64-bit compiler on Windows 7 SP 1.  Ultimately, I wish to compile mex-files for use with Matlab (R2014a).  I have an older computer which I successfully configured to do this using older versions of CUDA and VS C++ Express, but I can't seem to get it to work with the newer packages.

I've installed CUDA 6.0 and Visual Studio C++ 2012 Express, which web readings suggest should work together.  I'm not sure whether I also need the Microsoft SDK, which used to be necessary in order to get the 64-bit compilers; it seems that these are included with VS these days.

I created a vcvars64.bat inside 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64'.  I also made a copy of the entire directory renamed to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64'.  These steps used to be necessary for older versions -- not sure if they still are.

However, when I try to compile, I get the following error:

> nvcc : warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are
>   deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.  nvcc : fatal
>   error : nvcc cannot find a supported version of Microsoft Visual
>   Studio. Only the versions 2008, 2010, and 2012 are supported 
>   Compilation errors found:  terminating.

I'm compiling as follows:

nvcc --cuda myfile.cu --output-file myfile.cpp

Following this I would call mex within Matlab to build the mex file.  But I can't get past this first step.  Does anybody know how nvcc determines where to look for the compiler, and how I can get it to recognize a supported compiler?  Note that 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe' is on the system path.

Comment: compiling from the command line in windows even with a proper install of VS and CUDA can require a lot of additional system path settings as well as additional command line switches for `nvcc`.  Your command line is not nearly complete enough, and you may have modify some of your windows path definitions.  did you know there is documentation for nvcc as well as command line help?

Comment: Thanks Robert -- the line I show used to work on my older installation, although it may have involved various path definitions I have now forgotten.  I can look into the documentation for nvcc.  But is any of this likely to solve the specific problem I am having?

Comment: The nvcc warning about compute_10 and sm_10 can be eliminated by specifying a newer architecure when compiling, such as `-arch=sm_20`.  The error about nvcc cannot find a supported version of MS Visual Studio, from my experience, requires proper use of the `-ccbin` switch to nvcc along with an appropriate set of system PATH definitions which I usually enter via START...(right click on)Computer...Properties...Advanced system settings...environment variables and then create or modify the PATH environment variable to include necessary paths to VS compilers and libs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run vcvars64.bat and matlab both from the command line. This makes the correct VS environment variables known to Matlab and nvcc.

Comment: I don't run vcvars64.bat directly myself -- I think it gets called some time during the compilation process, if I'm not mistaken.  I have been making the call to nvcc via Matlab's system command.  Are you suggesting it would help to run vcvars64.bat immediately before the call to nvcc?  And do you know the answer to my question about how nvcc decides whether a supported compiler is installed?

Comment: I recognized the error that you described in a situation where Matlab lacked support for VS 2012 express. `mex -setup` just wouldn't recognize VS. I resorted to manual compilation without the mex facility: nvcc generates object code, and link generates a dll which is renamed mexw32/mexw64. For this to work, I wrote a batch file to run vcvars32/vcvars64 followed by matlab to set the environment variables. Without running vcvars32/64 explictly ahead of matlab I would get the same error as described by you. I'd wish for a less involved method, but this one works like a charm for me.